# What Graphics drivers do I need? (Ubuntu)

Tags: ubuntu, audio, drivers, graphics-card

I need graphics drivers for my "video card" to get audio out from displayport. The issue is I don't know exactly what drivers I need. I tried installing the desktop version of the graphics driver for my card from the amd website, which worked, but for some reason, it limited my cpu to only 1 out of 4 cores.

Specs:
4 gb of ram
amd cpu (sorry, not sure which exact model)
ubuntu 12.04 32-bit
The computer is a small one mounted on the back of a Samsung touchscreen

below is the output of `lspci -vk | egrep -iA13 "vga|audio"` which includes the graphics card info

```
lspctemp@temp-Aspire-V5-431P:~$ lspci -vk | egrep -iA13 "vga|audio"
00:01.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI BeaverCreek [Mobility Radeon HD 6620G] (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI BeaverCreek [Mobility Radeon HD 6620G]
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 53
    Memory at e0000000 (32-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    I/O ports at 3000 [size=256]
    Memory at f0a00000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256K]
    Expansion ROM at <unassigned> [disabled]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: radeon
    Kernel modules: radeon

00:01.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI BeaverCreek HDMI Audio [Radeon HD 6500D and 6400G-6600G series]
    Subsystem: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI BeaverCreek HDMI Audio [Radeon HD 6500D and 6400G-6600G series]
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 54
    Memory at f0a44000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd-hda-intel

00:10.0 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Hudson USB XHCI Controller (rev 03) (prog-if 30 [XHCI])
    Subsystem: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Hudson USB XHCI Controller
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 18
    Memory at f0a48000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=8K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd

--
00:14.2 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Hudson Azalia Controller (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Hudson Azalia Controller
    Flags: slow devsel, IRQ 16
    Memory at f0a40000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel modules: snd-hda-intel

00:14.3 ISA bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Hudson LPC Bridge (rev 11)
    Subsystem: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Hudson LPC Bridge
    Flags: bus master, 66MHz, medium devsel, latency 0

00:14.4 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Hudson PCI Bridge (rev 40) (prog-if 01 [Subtractive decode])
    Flags: bus master, 66MHz, medium devsel, latency 64
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=01, subordinate=01, sec-latency=64
```

Comment: You shouldn't need any other thing installed but the kernel to get HDMI/DP sound, as long as the KMS driver is loaded (`Kernel driver in use: radeon`). If it doesn't work then maybe there is a bug in the kernel version you're using (or PEBKAC in user space).

Comment: `I tried installing the desktop version of the graphics driver for my card from the amd website, which worked, but for some reason, it limited my cpu to only 1 out of 4 cores.` How did you figure Catalyst did that? It doesn't sound making any sense.

Comment: @TomYan I know, it's really weird. But I used to have 4 cpu cores, and the only thing I did was install that driver, and boom- down to one core. Could be something about an integrated gpu on the cpu??

Comment: Boom HOW? You mean `lscpu` and `/proc/cpuinfo` changed or what?

Comment: gnome-system-monitor used to show 4 cores, now it only shows 1, and that one is maxed out and laggs whenever playing video

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue on Ubuntu 14.04, in order to fix this problem I needed to find & install newer version of Ubuntu kernel.

Comment: weird thing is, all I had to do was reinstall the OS, and suddenly the install extra drivers feature worked.